# How to Bind two DataGridColumns Widths in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm aware of `DataGridColumns` not being on the logical nor visual tree of a grid. I'm using the proxy as shown [here](http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).

I need to bind the width of some of the columns. I usually use bindings like this one:

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LastOperationColumn}
```

However, it is not working. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `ElementName` in a DataGrid column because they are not objects in the visual or logical tree, they have no namescope which is needed for those bindings. You can however use `Source` and [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx):

```xml
{Binding ActualWidth, Source={x:Reference LastOperationColumn}}
```

Of course this won't change that the binding is destroyed if this column is resized manually.

Comment: They are fixed size so no problem at all. Thanks.

Comment: Mmm ... I'm hitting what seems to be a known defect: Error 5 Service provider is missing the INameResolver service.

Comment: @SoMoS: It worked for me at run time, so my guess would be that this is a gui designer error, can you run it?

Comment: HB: Yes, it's reported to be a designer error but makes it unusable :\ I think I'm gonna simulate the binding thru codebehind in the constructor.

Comment: @SoMoS: Well, each their own, i for one would say that the designer is *unusable by design*.

Comment: I have an attached property that I set on a `DataGridColumn`. But in this attached property I have to refer back to the `DataGridColumn` for some specific property. Using your `x:Reference` solution did not work when purely defining my attached property as a property element. I got a parse exception complaining about cyclical dependency. So I defined my attached property (the value of it anyway) as a resource and the it worked just fine. This is on a complex implementation of a `DataGrid` that does `SQL` filtering etc.

tldr: Thanks, it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at some code where I'm setting MaxWidth and I think it should be the same. Here's the syntax I used.

```
<DataGridTextColumn...     
    MaxWidth="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, 
                                            Mode=OneWay, 
                                            Path=DescriptionMaxWidth}">
```

Comment: No, it's not the same because I need to bind one column to another one, this is different to binding one column to a setting.

Comment: Is different means it does not makes sense in my scenario. No need to be rough. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `Width="{Binding  Path=ActualWidth,ElementName=LastOperationColumn}"`

Comment: I'm already using this binding. Path is the default property of a Binding ... and it's not working at all.

Comment: That did not deserve a -1.  I gave you a +1 to get back to 0.

Comment: @BalamBalam: Why not? It says nothing new and it is not helpful.

Comment: @SoMoS: There is no such thing as a "default property" on a markup extension, you can however invoke [a constructor which sets the path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578.aspx), which may or **may not** lead to the same results as setting the path property directly.